# mvc 5 if dropdownlist selected option than required different model property

Tags: javascript, c#, mvvm, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a view with multiple controls in it. What I want is when 1 of my dropdownlists have a specific value selected IF that value is selected then I want a different control property to be required. This property usually isn’t required normally. I only want it to be a requirement if this value is selected in my dropdownlist. In my model I usually can just Add required to a property but how can I do this like I asked above. If ‘usuage=value1’ then Quantity + Units required.  Is there a way to do this in the controller action? Or only possible via JavaScript. Here is my code for this situation.

```
<div class="form-group row">
<div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4">
@Html.LabelFor(x => x.Usage,
htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
</div>
<div class="col-md-8 col-lg-8">
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Usage,
(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>) ViewBag.UsageDDL,
"", new { @class = "form-control" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Usage, "",
new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>
</div> <div class="form-group row">
<div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4">
@Html.LabelFor(x => x.Quantity,
htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
</div>
<div class="col-md-8 col-lg-8">
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Quantity, new { htmlAttributes =
new { @class = "form-control", @type = "number" }})
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Quantity, "",
new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>
</div>

<div class="form-group row">
<div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4">
@Html.LabelFor(x => x.Units,
htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
</div>
<div class="col-md-8 col-lg-8">
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Units,
(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>) ViewBag.UnitsDDL,
"", new { @class="form-control" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Units, "",
new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The model can't be changed dynamically, so you probably want to create your own validation methods.  (Client and server-side.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you definitely need to use client-side code(obviously javascript) although might you can do it completely server-side but it's crossing the stream where it is shallowest.

You can use some thing like this:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Usage", new SelectListItem[] 
{ 
 new SelectListItem() { Text = "one", Value = "0" }, 
 new SelectListItem() { Text = "two", Value = "1" }},
 new { @onchange="handler(this.value)" 
});

<script>
function handler(val){
    //option1 : refresh current page based on Usage and make Quantity and Unit desabled in your Razor Page.
    window.location.href = "/Controller/CurrentAction?Usage=" + val;
    // option2 : make Quantity and Unit desabled by javascrip code without refresh page.
    var form = document.forms[0];
    form.querySelector('input[name="Quantity"]').disabled = true;
    form.querySelector('input[name="Unit"]').disabled = true;
}
</script>
```

I hope this will help you